# Framework for socket connection java + as3(flash) is there one?

Tags: java, sockets, actionscript

http://powergeek.ru/index2.php - here are a mini framework to connect java + as3, my question is, is there some similar frameworks?

Comment: Do you mean socket or call back connection?

Comment: I mean an mvc or not even mvc, just for comfortable use socket java + as3 connection, or some similar framework

Comment: Is your actionscript running in a browser or Air?

Comment: its just an swf file, I can execute it by double click, or embed it to the browser

Answer (score 0):

Executed from a flashplayer, you will have access to networking components. For [example](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_5.html).
Executed from a browser your SWF will be bound to the sandbox (as in no  network access).
In this scenario, you should have a look at [BlazeDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlazeDS) to have a realtime conversation between your SWF and a Java backend.
I have been using it in production for few years with great results.

Comment: Don't forget Granite Data Services as well which is even more powerful with tight integration with JEE.